# Configuring ActiveMQ 5.6.0 as a UNIX service on CentOS 32bit from command line

Tags: linux, apache, centos, activemq-classic

I can currently start ActiveMQ using xbean but ActiveMQ is not starting as UNIX service on boot

```
/home/username/activemq/bin/activemq start xbean:/home/username/activemq/conf/my-activemq.xml
```

the console prompted me to run setup so i

```
/home/username/activemq/bin/activemq setup etc/default/activemq
```

I'm confused why the console says to create a config file if I'm using xbean

then i created producer.php and consumer.php

```
cd /etc/init.d/

cat > producer.php

<?php
$queue1  = '/queue/queue1';
try {$stomp = new Stomp('tcp://localhost:61613');} 
catch(StompException $e) {die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());}
for($i=1;$i<10;$i++){$msg1 = "queue one my data".$i; 
$stomp->send($queue1, $msg1, array('persistent' => 'true'));}    
unset($stomp);
?>

cat > consumer.php

<?php 
$queue1  = '/queue/queue1';
try {$stomp = new Stomp('tcp://localhost:61613');}
catch(StompException $e) {die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());}
$stomp->subscribe($queue1);
while(1){$frame = $stomp->readFrame();
if ( $frame != null) {echo $frame->body; //process your message
echo "\n";  
$stomp->ack($frame);}} unset($stomp);
?>
```

started consumer.php with nohup

```
nohup php consumer.php > consumer.log 2>&1 &
```

it returned this to the console

```
[1] 32707
```

created startup file

```
cat > activemqstart.sh

#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr
/usr/share/php/activemq/bin/activemq &
```

created stop file

```
cat > activemqstop.sh

#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr
/usr/share/php/activemq/bin/activemq-admin stop
```

service configuration script

```
cat > activemq

#!/bin/bash
#
# activemq       Starts ActiveMQ.
#
# chkconfig: 345 88 12
# description: ActiveMQ is a JMS Messaging Queue Server.
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: $activemq
### END INIT INFO

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

[ -f /etc/init.d/activemqstart.sh ] || exit 0
[ -f /etc/init.d/activemqstop.sh ] || exit 0

RETVAL=0

umask 077

start() {
   echo -n $"Starting ActiveMQ: "
   daemon /etc/init.d/activemqstart.sh
   echo
   return $RETVAL
}
stop() {
   echo -n $"Shutting down ActiveMQ: "
   daemon su -c /etc/init.d/activemqstop.sh activemq
   echo
   return $RETVAL
}
restart() {
   stop
   start
}
case "$1" in
start)
   start
   ;;
stop)
   stop
   ;;
restart|reload)
   restart
   ;;
*)
   echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
   exit 1
esac

exit $?
```

then i set permissions

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/activemqstart.sh
chmod +x /etc/init.d/activemqstop.sh
chmod +x /etc/init.d/activemq
/sbin/chkconfig --add activemq
/sbin/chkconfig activemq on
```

cleared the actviemq.log

```
cat /dev/null > /home/username/activemq/data/activemq.log
```

rebooted

```
reboot
```

and checked the log but it's empty and ActiveMQ is not running

```
more /home/username/activemq/data/activemq.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this command locally

```
daemon /etc/init.d/activemqstart.sh
```

I tried the same and above command did not work for me since daemon was not avalable.

If so, try below, instead of above.

```
/etc/init.d/activemqstart.sh
```